# Install a package without install dependencies globally

Tags: software-installation

I want to a install recoll, but my question applies to packages that rely on dependencies.

I don't use python, but when I add the recoll PPA and try to install the package, apt wants to install many python libraries as dependencies for recoll.

So my question is.. is there a way to install a package with all dependencies packaged within a folder so I don't pollute my system with all these dependencies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape dependency hell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144640/how-to-escape-dependency-hell) . Or isolate it to its own docker container.

Comment: @N0rbert I don't think close voting this question as a duplicate of another question is the best policy because user535733 has posted an answer with a different concise and elegant alternative solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. Deb packages (the kind apt uses) have specified install locations. You cannot change them.

However, you might be asking the wrong question or looking in the wrong place:

- The `python3-recoll` package is in the Ubuntu repositories -- a PPA is not needed. The package adds a single additional dependency to a stock Ubuntu 21.10 test install, which hardly seems like *polluting* the system.

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather have 3rd party applications being managed by apt though so I can know what all I have installed in my system. Also, I was following the instructions from the recoll website: https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pages/download.html#ubuntu
I opt to use docker instead.